# Open iPhone settings through code not working in iOS 5.1.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location, ios5.1

i tried these commands-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Wallpaper"]];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Safari"]];
```

These codes opens Location, General, Wallpaper and Safari respectively in iOS 5.0 but nothing works in iOS 5.1.1
Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 5.1, the `prefs:` URL scheme has been removed. You can't use it anymore.

If using private APIs is an option, you can try this:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.Preferences"), false);
```

You have to link against the SpringBoardServices framework then.

Comment: `com.apple.Preferences` (capital P) worked for me in iOS 5.1/6.1.

Comment: @newenglander Thanks, good to know, edited. Now that you say, `preferences` (with lowercase `p`) is the bundle ID of the Preferences private framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to @H2CO3's answer (that wouldn't fit in comments). I was using that solution in my Cydia app to open the settings, combined with an entitlements file containing the following entry:

```
<key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
<string>true</string>
```

This was I believe the way Xcode formatted the entitlements file. And this worked fine on my two test devices. However, several beta testers mentioned that the settings app wasn't being opened. I noticed that several examples of entitlements files used a different format to indicate the value of a key:

```
<true/>
```

I tried this out on a device that didn't work with the first entitlements entry, and the settings app actually opened.

So I'm posting this in case anyone else has a similar problem. (Running the app as root may also be a solution, but I didn't try that.)